# Callback function and do while loop issue

Tags: javascript

```
var game = {
    setPlayerNum: function(){
        var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter Number of Players"));
        this.setPlayerName();
    },

    setPlayerName: function(){
        if (num == 2){
            do {
                var playerOne = prompt("Enter Your Name");
                } while(true){
                var playerTwo = prompt("Enter Your Name");
                break;
            }
        }

    },

    boardInitialize: function(){

    },

    boardInitializeView: function(){

    },

}
```

I have two functions with an object. First function runs fine, but the callback function isn't running. I am not sure why

Comment: Your loop has wrong syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. A scope issue, and an unnecessary and badly formatted while loop. Try this:

```js
var game = {

    num: 0,
    playerOne: '',
    playerTwo: '',

    setPlayerNum: function(){
        this.num = parseInt(prompt("Enter Number of Players"));
        this.setPlayerName();
    },

    setPlayerName: function(){

        this.playerOne = prompt("Enter Your Name");
        
        if (this.num == 2){

            this.playerTwo = prompt("Enter Your Name");
            
        }
    }
}

game.setPlayerNum();
```

To explain the scope issue a bit more: the `num` variable that you originally declared in your `setPlayerNum` method, was not available to the other methods outside of that scope. By declaring the `num` variable first, as part of the object, you can reference it. I have done the same to your `playerOne` and `playerTwo` variables.

But you might find it a bit nicer to re-arrange the script so that you can have any number of players:

```js
var game = {

  playerNames: [],

  setPlayerNum: function(){
    
    var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter Number of Players"));
    
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      
      this.setPlayerName(i + 1);
      
    }
  },

  setPlayerName: function(num){

    this.playerNames.push( prompt("Enter Your Name For Player " + num) );

  }
}

game.setPlayerNum();
```

Comment: Thank you. My break in the setPlayerName property is illegal. How else can I break out of that do while loop?

Comment: @HarryPotter you can break out of a `do...while` loop using the `break;` statement, but your loop was not formatted correctly. Look at [this info on do...while loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while). What is it you're trying to achieve in the `setPlayerName` method?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the syntax of the do/while statament. You can't open a scope after the while, you should end the do/while statement there with a ";".
Check this

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp.

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but I'm guessing that the do/while is not necesary. You could do something like this:

```
function() {
    var playerOne = prompt("Enter Your Name");
    if (this.num == 2){
        var playerTwo = prompt("Enter Your Name");
    }
}
```